# Cannot SSH to VM

Tags: ssh

I have a VM installed with some custom disk image (CentOS) from work, and I can't SSH into the VM.

Here are some things I've tried:

```
[VM]$ ssh root@localhost
Password:
```

Great, ssh is working with the loopback.

But when I try from the host machine:

```
~/VirtualBox VMs% ssh -v -v -v root@192.168.56.1
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.1 [192.168.56.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.56.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

Nada. Ping works though.

on the VM, /etc/hosts.allow:

```
ssh:ALL:allow
sshd:ALL:allow
```

nothing in hosts.deny

EDIT:
I've also done:

```
service iptables save
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

EDIT:
I'm also seeing this message on the VM in /var/log/secure
[image: bind to port conflict]
But I can ssh just fine from the VM to the VM, so this isn't the issue, right?

EDIT:
`[VM]$ lsof -i :22`
[image: lsof -i :22 output]

And I have, in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

And cannot login with a separate username.

EDIT:
 `netstat -pant |grep :22` and  `netstat -ntp |grep :22`
[image: netstat -pant and netstat -ntp]
I think maybe this also points towards the IPv6 solution?

EDIT:
Existing config for 
`vi /etc/sysctl.conf`
[image: /etc/sysctl.conf]

New config for
`vi /etc/sysctl.conf`
[image: /etc/sysctl.conf after change]
I then ran the commands:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
chkconfig ip6tables off
service sshd restart
init 6
```

Aaaaaaand, still nothing. But after a restart, it looks like ipv6 isn't disabled. I'm getting the same error message. 
[image: cannot bind port 22]
And `lsof -i :22` is still saying type IPv6:
[image: lsof -i :22]

EDIT: Going further down the IPv6 rabbit hole.
http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/01/12/disabling-ssh-connections-on-ipv6/
It says to remove the commented line with `#ListenAddress ::`, which seems fishy, cause it's already commented out. So I did, and nothing.

However, the next section has a useful tidbit:
`AddressFamily inet # IPv4 only`
When I add this line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and do a couple consecutive restarts, I now see that my address binding error has stopped appearing in `/var/log/secure`
[image: /var/log/secure]
and the output of `lsof -i :22` now shows a type of IPv4!
[image: yay, progress! lsof -i :22 shows IPv4]
Progress!! But unfortunately I still cannot connect. I tried rebooting the VM, opening new shell windows just in case there was some state left hanging around. Still the same answer.

```
~% ssh -vvv root@192.168.56.1
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.1 [192.168.56.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.56.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

EDIT:
ok, so i got arp-scan and am trying to find IP conflicts, but now i'm even more confused. 
ifconfig shows that vboxnet0, which is the host-only adapter, has an IP of 192.168.56.1. That's where I got that IP to begin with.

```
[local]~root# ifconfig  
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 7c:d1:c3:e8:b0:e9 
    inet6 fe80::7ed1:c3ff:fee8:b0e9%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 10.6.12.46 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 10.6.13.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0e:d1:c3:e8:b0:e9 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
vboxnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
    inet 192.168.56.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255
vboxnet1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 
    inet 192.168.57.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.57.255
```

But `arp-scan -l` gives only domains starting with 10.6.*.*
So I guess it's looking at en0? So I tried
`arp-scan -I vboxnet0 -l`

```
mba-108-on-03:~ root# arp-scan -I vboxnet0 -l
Interface: vboxnet0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.56.100  08:00:27:bc:ed:2f   CADMUS COMPUTER SYSTEMS

512 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8: 256 hosts scanned in 1.301 seconds (196.77 hosts/sec). 1 responded
```

Why is it now .100? #confused

vboxnet1 has nothing

```
mba-108-on-03:~ root# arp-scan -I vboxnet1 -l
Interface: vboxnet1, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)

512 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8: 256 hosts scanned in 1.302 seconds (196.62 hosts/sec). 0 responded
```

All of the other interfaces don't work with arp-scan.

So let's show duplicates on the en0 interface:

```
mba-108-on-03:~ root# arp-scan -I en0 -l |grep DUP
10.6.12.68  84:8e:0c:75:5b:f4   (Unknown) (DUP: 2)
10.6.12.64  ac:cf:5c:42:24:47   (Unknown) (DUP: 2)
10.6.12.76  88:53:95:6e:6a:af   (Unknown) (DUP: 2)
```

These numbers don't correspond to anything meaningful for me. Going to try a reboot, then the IPv6 suggestion.

EDIT:
The VM is a VirtualBox.
Adapter 1: NAT
Adapter 2: Host-only Adapter, 'vboxnet0'
[image: config of adapter1]
[image: config of adapter2]
Any ideas?

Comment: answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/30080/how-to-solve-connection-refused-errors-in-ssh-connection might help

Comment: Try attached to bridge

Comment: using "Bridged Adapter" gets the same result

Comment: What is the output of `lsof -i :22`?

Comment: Look like ip conflict

Comment: @SHW IP conflict if ping works?

Comment: Yeah. IP conflict means, two machine having same IP. In that case, ping will work but may be with some latency or delay

Comment: Can you also supply the output of `netstat -ntp | grep :22`?  On my system `lsof -i :22` doesn't show sockets in `TIME_WAIT`, `CLOSE_WAIT`, etc.

Comment: netstat -pant |grep :22 has output, included above. 
netstat -ntp |grep :22 does not have output. also included above.

Comment: Oh, just to be clear, you should run `netstat` immediately after restarting the sshd service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's how it finally came together:

One of my coworkers recalled that the disk image "might not have a second interface enabled." Since the VBox is set up with NAT as adapter one and Host-only as adapter two, you need to have eth0 and eth1 set up on the disk image. We did not.

To do this:

- verify that `ifconfig |less` does not have both eth0 and
  eth1 listed.
- `cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`
- `cp ifcfg-eth0 ifcfg-eth1`
- `cp ifcfg-eth0.bak ifcfg-eth1.bak`
- edit the files and remove anything with `HWaddr` and change eth0 to eth1
  [image: ifcfg-eth1]
- `ifup eth1`
- then run `ifconfig` and take the `inet addr` of eth1, which was a different IP for me. I'm now working with 192.168.56.101.
- do init 6 to restart and make sure that eth1 starts automatically now.
- log in from host: `ssh root@192.168.56.101`

None of the edits in the question above were actually my problem, but it's all good debug info!!

Cheers,
Ken

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the ssh daemon is using IPv6 (from the output of `lsof -i :22`) while you are trying to connect with IPv4. The system won't know how to route the traffic.

I am not sure about the IP conflict you are seeing, but would suggest trying the following:

1. Disable IPv6

   Add the following to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

   ```
   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
   ```

   Disable IPv6 on the running system

   ```
   sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
   sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
   ```

   Disable iptables for IPv6

   ```
   chkconfig ip6tables off
   ```
2. Restart something!

   You will have to restart the `ssh` daemon or the OS for the changes to take effect.

   So restart `sshd`

   ```
   service sshd restart
   ```

   Or restart the OS itself

   ```
   init 6
   ```

Don't forget you may not have a route to the host and may think about using bridged mode so your DHCP server can hand out a correct address.

You may also want to read the [CentOS Wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS6?action=show#head-d47139912868bcb9d754441ecb6a8a10d41781df) for more info about disabling IPv6

Comment: I tried your commands, but they don't appear to have disabled ipv6. I'm still receiving the binding error in the /var/log/secure, and lsof -i :22 is still reporting a type of ipv6

Comment: got sshd to report IPv4, but it didn't fix the problem. :\

Comment: well, reading your post it seems there was two problems, IPv4 routing and ethernet adapter configuration. I am glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is refused because you're trying to ssh as a root user? (I could be wrong).

try:

```
ssh <host_username>@<ipaddress>
```

Also are you using a mac?
If so, try turning on remote login from System Preferences->Sharing check Remote Login.

Comment: I have 
    PermitRootLogin yes and I can login as another username that I created.

Comment: turn on remote login? but i'm not trying to login to the mac, which is the host machine. I'm trying to login to the VM, which is configured as a CentOS 5.4 box.

Comment: Ohh! I'm sorry, I misread your question. My bad!